# AngularJs is not working after calling a php file

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in `header.php` and `create_test.php` files. It is working fine when I execute the files separately.
Then I am calling this `header.php create_test.php` file.

After calling `create_test.php` file AngularJS codes are not working.

Why is it so? Can anyone assist me to solve this?

In header.php file,

```
<?php
//calling methods of methods.php file
include'C:/wamp64/www/performance/header/src/demo/methods.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/performance/login/images/merahkee.png" /> 
    <title> Merahkee Technology Soluctions</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- SmartMenus jQuery Bootstrap 4 Addon CSS -->
    <link href="../addons/bootstrap-4/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Angularjs-->
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.9" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <!--This version is for title attribute-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <!--Angularjs starts-->
    <script src="http://localhost/performance/header/src/addons/bootstrap-4/header.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding-top:80px;">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div ng-app="rootApp" class="container">
        <a ng-app = "firstApp" ng-controller = "firstController" class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{ pageTitle }}</a>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <!-- Left nav -->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <!--Display project dropdown-->
            <li ng-app = "thirdApp" ng-controller = "thirdController" class="nav-item dropdown" style="padding-right:15px;" ><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{Project}}</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <?php
                  echo '<li><a class="dropdown-item">Recent Projects </a></li>';
                      for($i=0;$i<$projectcount;$i++){
            //calling test_name() method and storing those values in a string
                        $test=project_name($count_uid,$user_id,$pro_sql);
                        $project_name=$test[$i];

                        if(strlen($project_name)>=25){
                            $projectName=substr($project_name,0,25);
                            $projectName=$projectName.'..';
                            }
                        else{
                            $projectName=$project_name;
                         } 
                        echo'<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost/performance/project/ShowTest_of_project.php?project_name='.$project_name.'&user_id='.$user_id.'" title="'.$project_name.'">'.$projectName.'</a></li>';
                     }//for loops ends

                    //show all projects 

                    echo'<li ng-app = "seventhApp" ng-controller = "seventhController"><a ng-repeat="x in sdc_pro" class="dropdown-item" href="{{x.href}}'.$user_id.'">{{x.name}}</a></li>';
             ?>
             </ul><!--dropdown-menu closes-->
          </li><!--project dropdown ends-->
            <li ng-app = "fourApp" ng-controller = "fourController" class="nav-item dropdown"><a style="padding-right:15px;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{Test}}</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <?php
                      echo '<li><a class="dropdown-item">Recent Tests </a></li>';
                          for($i=0;$i<$testcount;$i++){
                                    //calling test_name() method and storing those values in a string
                                    $test1=recent_test1($test_sql);
                                    $test_name1=$test1[$i];
                                    //project name
                                    $project=recentTest_project($test_sql);
                                    $project_name=$project[$i];
                                    //platform file name
                                    $platform=platform_file();
                                    $platform_file=$platform[$i];

                                    //project id
                                    $project_id=pro_id($test_sql);
                                    $pro_id=$project_id[$i];

                                   //calling file_name() method and storing those values in a string
                                    //$file=load_file_name();
                                    //$file_name=$file[$i];

                                    //echo' <a type="submit" name="testname"  href='.$file_name.'>'.$test_name.'</a><br>';


                                   if(strlen($test_name1)>=25){
                                        $testName=substr($test_name1,0,25);
                                        $testName=$testName.'..';
                                    }
                                     else{
                                        $testName=$test_name1;
                                    }
                            echo'<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost/performance/RunTest_09.php?test_name='.$test_name1.'&project_name='.$project_name.'" title="'.$test_name1.'">'.$testName.'</a></li>';
                         }//for loops ends
                    //show all projects ,delete project and create project  
                  echo'<li ng-app = "eighthApp" ng-controller = "eigthController"><a ng-repeat="x in sdc_test" class="dropdown-item" href="{{x.href}}'.$user_id.'">{{x.name}}</a></li>';
                ?>
              </ul>   
            </li><!--test dropdown ends-->
            <li ng-app = "fifthApp" ng-controller = "fifthController" class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{Report}}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li><!--report list ends-->
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li ng-app = "sixthApp" ng-controller = "sixthController"  class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{default}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a ng-repeat="x in details" class="dropdown-item" href="{{x.href}}">{{x.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>      
          </ul>
       </div><!--collapse navbar-collapse-->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- SmartMenus jQuery plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/performance/header/src/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>
    <!-- SmartMenus jQuery Bootstrap 4 Addon -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/performance/header/src/addons/bootstrap-4/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap-4.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In cteate_test file,

```
<?php
  include_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Performance\header\src\demo\header.php';
  include_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Performance\project\methods\methods.php'; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
       function ConfirmDelete() {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
           }
    </script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/performance/project/css/showAllProject.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Angularjs-->
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script >
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("namesCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'PROJECT'},
        {name:' |DESCRIPTION'},
        {name:' |CREATEDON'},
        {name:' |LASTUPDATED'},
        {name:' |'},
    ]
    $scope.hrefs = [
        {href:'http://localhost/performance/deleteProject_showAll_pro.php?project_name=',src:'http://localhost/performance/css/delete.png',title:'delete',alt:'delete',onclick:'return ConfirmDelete()'},
        {href:'http://localhost/performance/editProject_form.php?project_name=',src:'http://localhost/performance/css/edit.ico',title:'edit',alt:'edit',onclick:''},
        {href:'http://localhost/performance/copyProject_form.php?project_name=',src:'http://localhost/performance/css/copy_pro.png',title:'copy',alt:'edit',onclick:''},
    ]
});
    </script>
</head>
<body  style="font-size:12px;">
<div class="row">
    <div  class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-10" id="col-lg-14" >     
        </div>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller ="namesCtrl" class="row vertical-center-row" id="myApp">
            <div class="col-lg-20" id="myApp-main">
                <div  class="row">
                    <div ng-repeat="x in names"  class="col" id="col">
                        {{x.name}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="project" >
     <?php

     for($i=0;$i<$procount;$i++){
         //calling test_name() method and storing those values in a string
         $project=project_name1($user_id);
         $project_name=$project[$i];
         //description
         $desctipt=project_description1($user_id);
         $description=$desctipt[$i];
         // project creation date
         $date=ProjectCreated_date($user_id);
         $created_on=$date[$i];
         //project edited on 
         $editDate=ProjectEdited_date($user_id);
         $edited_on=$editDate[$i];
            //for displaying the project                         
             if(strlen($project_name)>=25){
                $projectName=substr($project_name,0,25);
                $projectName=$projectName.'..';
                }
             else{
                $projectName=$project_name;
              } 
              //for displaying the description of the project
            if(strlen($description)>=25){
                $description=substr($description,0,25);
                $description=$description.'..';
                }
             else{
                $description=$description;
             }
             //display project name, discription,created date and deleted date date 
            echo '<div class="row" id="row" ng-mouseover="changeImage=true" ng-mouseleave="changeImage=false" ng-init="changeImage=false">';

            //projectName
                 echo'<div class="col">';
                    echo $projectName;
                 echo '</div>';
            //description    
                 echo'<div class="col" >';
                    echo $description;
                 echo '</div>';
            //created date
                 echo'<div class="col" >';
                    echo $created_on;
                 echo '</div>';
            //last updated date
                 echo'<div class="col" >';
                    echo $edited_on;
                 echo '</div>';
            //
                 echo'<div class="col col-sm-1" ng-repeat="x in hrefs">';

                    echo '
                          <a href="{{x.href}}'.$project_name.'"><img  src="{{x.src}}" title="{{x.title}}" alt="{{x.alt}}" style="width:15px;height:15px;border:0;" Onclick=""/></a>';
                          //<a href="'.$project_name.'" "><img ng-show="changeImage" src="http://localhost/performance/css/edit.ico" title="edit"  alt="running test" style="width:15px;height:15px;border:0;margin-left:0.5cm"></a>
                          //<a href="'.$project_name.'" "><img ng-show="changeImage" src="http://localhost/performance/css/copy_pro.png" title="copy"  alt="running test" style="width:15px;height:15px;border:0;margin-left:0.5cm"/></a>';
                 echo '</div>';          
            echo'</div>';//display project name, discription,created date and deleted date date div ends
        echo '<hr id="hr">';}//for loop ends
      ?>
       </div> <!--project div ends-->
         <div class="col-lg-12" id="createProject" >
            <center><a href="http://localhost/performance/project_form.php?user_id='.$user_id.'"><img src="http://localhost/performance/css/create.png" title="Create Test" alt="Create New Project" id="createProjectIMG"></a></center>
         </div> 
      </div><!--myApp div ends-->
    </div><!--container-fluid div ends-->
  </div><!--row div ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code to describe your issue better?

Comment: I have updated the code